# How to convert column types by a column name -> type name mapping

Tags: r, types, dataframe

Consider this sample data:

```
structure(list(myNumbers = c(1, 2, 3), myLetters = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("myNumbers", "myLetters"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

As well as a vector of new column names for the data like:

```
c("newNumbers", "newLetters")
```

My workflow involves creating this vector of new column names by asking the user whether an existing column name should be replaced by a predefined standard name. The result is a vector with column name replacements. This is necessary because I like to prepare data from different sources (with similar content but changing variable names) to be processed in a standardized way.

The next step of the workflow is to do the necessary data type conversions. For the example, consider the column `myLetters`, which is now factor, shall become character and will be called `newLetters` in the resulting DF. I like to link the wanted data types to the standard column names. In this case, the workflow should use a mapping like (pseudocode!):

```
newNumbers -> as.numeric ()
newLetters -> as.character()
```

I then like to use this mapping (which will be stored with the standard column names) to automate the data type conversions as far as possible. So the process will be:

Check the column name -> find correct data type (thus the mapping) -> convert to the given data type.

I can perform type conversions for a list of columns with the `colwise` function of the `plyr` package. However, this does not work with the mapping described above. The mapping per name is necessary since it might be that some columns are missing or that there will be additional columns which will not get a standard name.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? If you just want to identify all the columns containing the string 'Numbers', try: `grepl('Numbers', names(df))`

Comment: No, what I want is to tell R that if it finds a column named 'newLetters', for example, it should convert this to character type.

Comment: Not much clear for me. What about `df[["newLetters"]]<-as.character(df[["newLetters"]])`?